# show NSProgressIndicator on top of webview

Tags: webview, nsprogressindicator

I dragged and dropped  progressindicator from main.xib on to a webview .

I need to show NSProgressIndicator on top of webview , instead of showing  on the same webview.

The main idea is to stop the enduser to access webview until and unless  NSProgressIndicator.stopAnimation(self) is done.

Can someone help me on this .

Answer (score 0):

//In order to show  a modelpanel on top of appdelegate.swift we need to  //follow two steps.

//step1: create a cocoa class  from NSWindowController as below.

import Cocoa

class ManuModalController: NSWindowController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var progressIndicator1: NSProgressIndicator!

```
var mainW: NSWindow = NSWindow()

override init()
{
    super.init()
}

override init(window: NSWindow!)
{
    super.init(window: window)
}

required init?(coder: (NSCoder!))
{
    super.init(coder: coder);
}

override func windowDidLoad()
{
    super.windowDidLoad()
}

func beginSheet(mainWindow: NSWindow)
{
    self.mainW = mainWindow;
    NSApp.beginSheet(self.window!, modalForWindow:  self.mainW, modalDelegate: self, didEndSelector:nil, contextInfo: nil);
    progressIndicator1.startAnimation(self);
}

@IBAction func btnClicked(sender: AnyObject)
{
    self.endSheet();
}

func endSheet()
{
    NSApp.endSheet(self.window!);
    self.window!.orderOut(mainW);
}
```

}

//step2 : create  the object of modalcontroller in appdelegate.swift as below

var mdlwin = ManuModalController(windowNibName: "ManuModalController");

mdlwin.beginSheet(self.window);//displays the modalpanel
   mdlwin.endSheet(); //closes the modal panel